# responseType in $.ajax

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, jqxhr

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "bla",
   xhrFields: { responseType: "document" },
   data: {},
   success: function(arg,arg2,request){
      console.log(request.responseXML)
   }
})
```

Why is it printing 'undefined'? How would I fix this?

Comment: As well as the answer below I must point out that the URL `bla` must tell the browser the content type is application/json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you expecting a JSON return? What happens when you try:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "bla",
  dataType: 'xml',
}).done(function (response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

If you look at [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), they outline how:

> The jQuery XMLHttpRequest (jqXHR) object returned by $.ajax() as of
>   jQuery 1.5 is a superset of the browser's native XMLHttpRequest
>   object. For example, it contains responseText and responseXML
>   properties, as well as a getResponseHeader() method.

The response variable therefore contains what you need. To see its structure, do a `console.log()` and go to the 'Console' tab in your Developer Tools (Chrome) or Firebug (Firefox).

Comment: I want to get the XML of the url not JSON.